# What does an empty AUTH EHLO SMTP response mean with MS Exchange?

Tags: exchange, smtp-auth, smtp

I'm a programmer, not a sys-admin, but my customer's sys-admins are not being helpful and after much googling I still can't find the answer to this.

My Java application gets the following response from my customer's MS Exchange following EHLO

```
EHLO PMNDEV3.prd.abc
250-PYTHON3.prd.abc Hello [155.5.200.100]
250-SIZE 20971520
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-AUTH
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250-XEXCH50
250 XSHADOW
```

Note that the 250-AUTH response has no parameters, so my software library (JavaMail) understandably says that it can't authenticate as there are no supported mechanisms advertised per [RFC 4954](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4954)

My question is why is this so? Is there perhaps some other non ESMTP authentication happening that is causing no AUTH mechanisms to be advertised?

Comment: If folks reach this question on account of a `AuthenticationFailedException javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: No authentication mechansims supported by both server and client` -- the easy workaround is to ensure that the `mail.smtp.auth` property is false, and thus not *attempt* to authenticate in a scenario where the server won't accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server's probably set up to not allow authentication over a plaintext connection.

What happens if you send `AUTH PLAIN` after the `EHLO`? Does it complain about `AUTH PLAIN` over a clear channel?

Comment: You are right. The server was set up to not allow authentication. Unfortunately the customer site is a secure environment and all my testing was done at arms length via their local sys-admins.